# How to draw a closed line in QGIS1.8?

Tags: qgis

I want to draw a closed line in QGIS1.8,but I don't know how to make the last point coincide with the first point.What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set the Snapping Options:**

This is a previous answer on GIS SE

[How to merge lines with slightly different endpoints in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/how-to-join-lines-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks,I thought that draw closed lines shoud be as easy as that in CAD,etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Snapping options don't work on a new line you are just creating.

Only way I found is to let the line open, save, and move the ends together with the node tool. You might get an error in geometry for that.

Or think of using polygon geometry....