# Building own CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, vector

I have a set of polylines which are described by a project-specific, local coordinate system. I would like to find a more or less accurate way of reprojecting these polylines to EPSG:28992. I have been looking into [building my own custom projection with pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs.html) but it looks like this is quite complicated.

I'd rather have an easier way. However, if there isn't, would anyone give me some pointers on how to start building my own coordinate system such that I can reproject my locally defined polylines to an EPSG based coordinate system like EPSG:28992?

Comment: What does this project-specific coordinate system look like? If it is cartesian, you could probably use just a vector translation and a rotation (if it is not already North oriented)

Comment: Yes. It is cartesian. I think some stretching might be needed as well, so I'm not sure if a simple translation+rotation would be sufficient. Now looking into this approach https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175642/georeferencing-vector-dataset-in-qgis

Comment: With translation I meant an addition *and* a multiplication (in other words: moving and stretching), so that should work

Comment: How can I do that for multiple polylines? Could you point to something from the literature? I have only found transformation matrices for one point coordinate at a time (2x2 matrix)

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `ogr2ogr` which works reasonably well for what I'm trying to achieve. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175642/georeferencing-vector-dataset-in-qgis) provides some further detail.

In addition to running the command line tool, I had to "Assign projection" to the resulting vector layer in QGIS. Since I am using a projected coordinate system I didn't have any issues.