# Import Vector data to QGIS from pdf and apply georeference

Tags: qgis, vector, mapinfo, pdf

I am Using QGIS 2.14. I have a PDF created by Mapinfo, it contains multiple layers of vector data that I can open as separate vector layers in QGIS.

However no map projection data was saved to the PDF. One of the vector layers is a UTM grid. Is it possible to manipulate the vector layers using the information from the grid layer and save as correctly located shp files?

Comment: So you can open the vector layers in QGIS as separate layers? Or does it bring them in as rasters? Can you then save them as shape file for example?

Comment: I you can save them as ShapeFiles then you could follow: http://gisforthought.com/georeferencing-vector-data-using-qgis-and-ogr2ogr/

Comment: Maybe the answers here can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/georeference-vector-linework/92892#92892