# How to fit polylines on base map layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, georeferencing

I have transformed a pdf into polyline and i want it to fit into the base map of OpenStreetMap.

How can I rotate and reduce the polylines layer?

With the image will be easier to know than I ask.

[image: The red polylines are the ones I want to fit where the blue arrow]

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop you wish to ask about in this particular question. Asking about both is effectively two questions which goes against the [Tour]. In ArcGIS Desktop the topic you should look at is Spatial Adjustment

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of info on this subject. Some answers and reference here on GIS.SE:

- [Import Vector data to QGIS from pdf and apply georeference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185837/import-vector-data-to-qgis-from-pdf-and-apply-georeference)
- [How to georeference a vector layer with control points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points)
- [Georeferencing vector dataset in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175642/georeferencing-vector-dataset-in-qgis)
- [Georeference vector linework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/georeference-vector-linework/92892)
- [More here...](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=georeference%20vector%20qgis)

See also a nice plugin named **Vector Bender** which allows simple transformation of your vector layer.

His author even posted an answer here :

- [How to align/georeference distorted vector layers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97596/how-to-align-georeference-distorted-vector-layers-in-qgis)

[image: Plugins]

[image: Plugin Screenshot]