# SVG's as map layers, any other way?

Tags: qgis, svg

I have a map in SVG format. I can import it as an SVG symbol, scale it, rotate it and geolocate it, all as a symbol. This is great as I get all the plusses of a scalable vector graphic. I.e. when I zoom in it doesn't get blurry. Is there any way to import the SVG, which clearly QGIS understands as, as vector map layers?

Comment: Welcome @Simon Allen, Please give users more details about your question. What does SVG map mean?  It's very important to add an image of this SVG. We will help you better when your questions are more clear.

Comment: This Q/A may be of some help to you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/georeferencing-vector-pdf-svg-dxf-linework-using-qgis

Comment: Here's another Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691541/qgis-how-to-import-svg-or-raster-images-into-quantum-gis

Comment: I understand they are not layered, but they consist of points, lines and polygons, just like any other vectors. Just hoped there was a quick and dirty way to load them as three layers. Like the GPX importer...

Comment: A symbol is something way different from a map. What projection is your SVG in and are its coordinate values corresponding to that or is it just visual?

Answer (score -1):

Scalable Vector Graphics or SVG don't consist of layers. They are merely (vector-)shapes on a two-dimensional plain.

Comment: SVGs can have layers.