# Extracting and georreferencing shapefiles from a PDF file

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf

I am trying to extract and georeference the orange polygons/lines from [this PDF file](https://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cidade/secretarias/upload/urbanismo/infocidade/mapas/9_distribuicao_das_favelas_2017_10251.pdf) of the city of São Paulo, in Brazil.

To do so, I am mostly trying to follow what was discussed in [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72674/georeferencing-vector-pdf-svg-dxf-linework-using-qgis), but none of the proposed solutions are working for me.

I tried using Adobe Illustrator to extract those and export to a DXF archive, but the QGIS step is curbing my advances.  I am working in EPSG 32723.  My first attempt was to use the affine transformation, but the imported shapefile could not pass through: all polygons had invalid geometries.

The attempt to use JOSM also failed.  I cannot process the output from downloading São Paulo's data.

Is there another path to extract those vector objects?

Comment: Why did you try JOSM? Is the data in OpenStreetMap?

Comment: I've loaded the PDF into Inkscape which lets me inspect the vector data under the orange areas, and its a real mess. Each orange polygon can be made of several parts, often overlapping, drawn in a very thick line, and sometimes not joining up as a polygon loop. I think it would be very difficult to extract useful vector data from this.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you.  I am unsure about how to use JOSM for this particular task.  An alternative file from the same set is https://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cidade/secretarias/upload/urbanismo/infocidade/mapas/9_distribuicao_das_favelas_2008_1.pdf

Comment: An alternative I am considering is to extract the orange polygons using Illustrator, forcing a conversion to raster, georreferencing, and then rebuilding the vectors.

Comment: Using QGIS 3.26, I could load your pdf as raster layer in the georeferencer, but not as a vector layer.