# Join (circular)polylines to create a polygon

Tags: qgis, line, polygon-creation

I'm trying to merge three polylines in order create a polygon out of the surface bordered by them.
On the picture attached, it's the region between the green, yellow and red (dotted) line that I would like to transform into a polyline.

I know two line segments can be joined into one line ([How to merge lines with slightly different endpoints in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/how-to-merge-lines-with-slightly-different-endpoints-in-qgis)), but how can I join them if the second line doesn't end anywhere near the other?

I'm working with QGIS 2.14.3-Essen, on a Mac (as one can see from the picture attached).

Hope someone can help me with this.

[image: polylines to polygon]

When the "Polygonize" algorithm is executed, a polygon is created of different regions, as you can see in the photo attached.

[image: Polygonized result]

And if I run the "Lines to Polygons" function I get this result:

[image: lines to Polygons]

Comment: The green Line must have a gap, otherwise it would form a Polygon.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage you have here is that these three lines crosses each other, which intersections can be used as cutting points. In three steps:

1. Merge all lines into one layer.
2. Cut them into segments at intersected points. To do this, activate `QGIS Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector overlay tools | Split lines with lines` and provide the subject layer to both *Input layer* and *Split layer*.
3. Join them together by a plugin [Join Multiple Lines](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/joinmultiplelines/) which gives an single Multistring (polyline).

To convert it (polyline) to polygon, you can use `Vector geometry tools | Lines to polygons`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see a "polygonize" algorithm listed in the processing toolbox? Running that algorithm on a merged layer containing the 3 linestrings should give you what you're after.

Comment: Wow, it's done in a quick single action!

Comment: Thanks for your help, although I did not get the result as I was hoping for. When I execute the "polygonize" algorithm, a polygon is created from other regions, as will be shown in a picture I add to my initial question.