# Creating a vector layer that fills the space between two line vector

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I need to create a polygon vector that fills the space between two line vectors I have.

[image: Workspace]

The black line vector represents the coastline, while the blue line vector indicates the 250m depth contour.

The idea is to create a polygon that represents the entire marine territory of the region that is under 250m depth (meaning, between the two line vectors)

Comment: It seems you have a small gap, at around NW corner, in your blue line vector layer. Do you wish to include the fixing process in the answer?

Comment: @Kazuhito No need! I fixed the gap already! Thank you for noticing!

Comment: Then it will be simple enough. (1) Make sure you have small overlap between coastline and blue line. (Slightly extend end nodes of blue line) (2) Merge (Vector | Data Management Tools | Merge Vector Tools) (3) Polygonize (see ndawson's [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226417/84455) ). I see @krvrd's good answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill the area between two line layers you need:

1. Merge layers through [Merge shapes plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mergeshapes/).
2. Then you'll must check are there gaps on the contour and fix them.
3. Apply vector tool "Lines to polygons". (Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Lines to polygons).

Done!

Comment: If you have several lines and output polygons, you can also use polygon instead of lines to polygons