# Raster to vector -> vector to mean line with one attribute

Tags: qgis, raster-to-point

I am using QGIS and I need to calculate the minimum distance from points to line.
I have the points in .txt format and this is ok, but I have to extract the line from the raster file showed the following figure:
[image]
So I made "raster to vector" and I have this situation

[image]

The vector file contains, of course, a lot of id values. 
My purpose is to have only 1 id value, that is having only a line shapefile.

I tried also to convert the vector file in lines, but the output was the following:
[image]

I would like to have only 1 line (like a "mean" line) which has only 1 attribute so that I can calculate the minimum distance from points.

Of course, if you know a different procedure to calculate the minimum distance between points and a raster, it is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the GRASS GIS tool `r.thin`, available from the QGIS processing toolbox applies to your problem. Citing the GRASS manual it 'thins non-NULL cells that denote linear features into linear features having a single cell width.' After applying `r.thin` to your raster you can use `r.to.vect` specifying line as the feature type.

Both tools are available in the processing toolbox. Here are the GRASS manual pages:
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.thin.html
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.to.vect.html

If you end up with multiple line segments you can use `v.clean` with the snap option to snap lines to vertices within a specified threshold. This, and various other options for combining multiple lines are discussed here: [How to merge lines with slightly different endpoints in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/how-to-merge-lines-with-slightly-different-endpoints-in-qgis)

Distance from points to the final vector line can then be found by use of `v.distance`, for example. This and some other options are given in answers to this question:
[Measuring the distance between lines and points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/measuring-the-distance-between-lines-and-points-in-qgis)

Comment: Thanks for your help!